# Prove that the random variables $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory

I'm studying probability from Durrett's book. And I found this exercise.
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be random variables over the former space.  We say that $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are independent if whenever $B_i\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb R)$

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle P \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\in B_i\}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n P(\{X_i\in B_i\})
\end{equation}

($\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb R)$ denotes the Borel sets over $\mathbb{R}$).

My problem is the following, suppose the random vector $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ has density f. If $f(\vec{x})=f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^ng_i(x_i)$, where the $g_i$ are nonnegative and measurable functions, then $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are independent. Note that the $g_i$'s are $\mathbb{not}$ assumed to be probability densities.

My attempt:

We know that $\forall A\in\mathfrak B(\mathbb R^n)$

\begin{equation}
P((X_1,\cdots,X_n)\in A)=\int_{A}f(\vec x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Also we know that f is a nonnegative and measurable function, so Fubini's theorem is valid and using the decomposition of f, it follows that
\begin{equation}
P((X_1,\cdots,X_n)\in A)=\prod_{i=1}^n \int_{A_{i}}g_i(x_i)\mathrm{d}x_i
\end{equation}
where $A=\prod_{i=1}^nA_i$, $A_i$ are Borel sets over $\mathbb R$. But I don't know how I can continue.

On one hand, I suspect that we need a suitable re-escalation of the $g_i$'s but don't know how to do it. On the other hand, I wonder if we can characterize the independence of the $X_1,\cdots, X_n$ by 
\begin{equation}
P((X_1,\cdots,X_n)\in A)=\prod_{i=1}^n \int_{A_{i}}g_i(x_i)\mathrm{d}x_i
\end{equation}

Comment: Use the fact that $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ has a density $f$,  the assumption that $f=\prod_{i=1}^n g_i$, and Fubini/Tonelli to compute $P(X_i\in A_i)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: "Note that the gi's are  assumed to be probability densities." Duly noted. But you can divide each of them by its integral to get a new representation of $f$ as a product whose factors ARE probability densities. Then your problem vanishes...

Comment: I realized how to finish this problem, thanks.